# Configuring zend to use gmail smtp: Windows Apache dev-environment: "Could not open socket" error - repeatedly - going mad

Tags: windows, zend-framework, sockets, gmail

My dev environment is Win XP SP2 / Apache 2.something PHP 5.something_or_other

My prod env is Linux Ubuntu / Apache 2.something_else PHP 5.something_or_other_else

The code is all Zend Framework Version: 1.11.1

I can telnet to: smtp.gmail.com 465 from the PC.

I have Mercury configured on my PC to use gmail as it's smtp host and it works just fine. (MercuryC SMTP Client). Mercury is set to use port 465 and SSL on smtp.gmail.com
 -- No problem.

Zend mail works just fine on my production environment using the production mail server to send out mail. It's the same basic application.ini but with different values in the mail variables.

On my local PC dev setup, my application.ini contains: (same values as I use in Mercury)

```
mail.templatePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/emails"
mail.sender.name = "myAccount"
mail.sender.email = "myAccount@gmail.com"
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.auth = "login"
mail.smtp.username = "myAccount@gmail.com"
mail.smtp.password = "myPassWord"
mail.smtp.ssl = "ssl"
mail.smtp.port = 465
```

I have been doing trial and error for hours trying to get a single email out with no success. In every case, regardless of server or port settings it throws an error and reports:

```
Could not open socket.
```

Both Apache and Mercury Core are exceptions in my Windows Firewall config. Mercury seems to be having no problem.

I have searched stackoverflow before posting this and have been googling for hours -- with no success.

I am slowly losing my mind

I would be very much obliged for any tip as to what might be wrong.

Thanks for reading.

===================

BTW

When I use the SAME application.ini values on my local PC as on the production host, I get the same "Could not open socket" error.

Those values are:

```
mail.templatePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/emails"
mail.sender.name = "otherUser"
mail.sender.email = "otherUser@otherAccount.com"
mail.host = smtp.otherServer.com
mail.smtp.auth = "login"
mail.smtp.username = "otherUser@otherAccount.com"
mail.smtp.password = "otherPAssWord"
mail.smtp.ssl = "ssl"
mail.smtp.port = 465
```

I know these work in the production (Ubuntu) environment.

I'm utterly baffled.

===============================================

It seems that down in the guts of the code the attempt to connect is written as:

```
$this->_socket = @stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
```

where **$remote** has the value:

```
ssl:\/\/smtp.gmail.com:465
```

... given the application.ini values up above in my current version -- according to the error message instrumentation I just put in.

Since it's working in production I rather doubt that there is something wrong with that. But ... just in case it helps, there it is.

Actually it looks normal enough to me.

==============================

It seems to be failing with an error number of 0 -- which I understand to mean that there is some sort of problem initializing the socket.

==============================

Just for sanity's sake I just checked php.ini and confirmed that both:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

... are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

OK folks. First I'd like to say, **!#$#%$#$##@$$$!#!$ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

That said, there were two problems hiding behind the surface. I'm going to leave the story here for them what comes behind me.

================================
Part 1

The geniuses who built the foundations of the Zend project I'm working on, very properly set up the appropriate mail parameters in application.ini as shown above.

They set up a default transport of sorts in a subdirectory of the site they called **Services**, by the name of **OurNameSpace_Service_Mail** in a file called **Mail.php**. Fine.

They then proceeded, down in the guts of that class to say:

```
$this->_smtpTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.somehost.com', array(
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => 'someID@otherHost.com',
    'password' => 'somePassWord',
    'ssl' => 'ssl',
    'port' => 465));
```

... thus ignoring the values they had carefully put into application.ini. ***Brilliant!***

A word of warning. The error messages issuing from **Zend/Mail/PRotocol/Abstract.php** and 
**Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php** don't expose much information about errors, so I had to instrument them myself. This is even more annoying when the error number is 0 as it was in my case.

Somebody ought to call the Nobel committee and nominate my project brainiacs for a best coding practices award! And thanks, Zend, for the useless error messages.

================================
Part 2

May the angels of heaven shower rewards on the head of the excellent fellow who put up this web page:

[PHP Windows install: Unable to load dynamic library php_mssql.dll, php_pspell.dll etc](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/php-windows-install-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php_mssql-dll-php_pspell-dll-etc/)

URL

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/php-windows-install-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php_mssql-dll-php_pspell-dll-etc/

What happened is this. In the hope that my logs might have something I looked in Apache's error.log, and found:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/php/ext/php_openssl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Of course this filled me with joy and satisfaction -- especially since I knew that the dll was enabled and, when I checked, it was right there in the ext directory, right where it should be. Misery.

As the page linked above explains, the problem turned out to be a missing dependency.

php_openssl.dll depends on a couple of other dll's that Apache was not finding the right versions for.

When I copied those dll's from PHP's root directory to Apache's bin directory, the problem went away. I wont repeat the contents of that excellent tech-tip page here.

Again, may the gifts of heaven fall on the techie that sorted out the solution and published it.

================

Happy coding.